# How to fix SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a yii2 application which works perfectly but now only one page is not working saying PDO exception error.

I tried changing the database in which I have a backup but it won't give result.

my controller page code is:

```
public function actionBoxedmainscreen() {
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->redirect([Yii::$app->homeUrl, 'loginmessage'=>'Access denied : Main Boxed Screen']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['width'])) {
        Yii::$app->session->set("width", $_GET['width']);
        Yii::$app->session->set("height", $_GET['height']);
    }

    $this->layout = 'mainscreen';
    $channels = Yii::$app->session->get('noOfChannels');
    $noOfChannels = ($channels != null) ? $channels : 32;

    $channels = \app\models\Channels::findBySql('Call GetWebChannels()')->all();
    $screenadjust = models\Displaysettingweb::findBySql('Select * from displaysettingweb where maxchannel >='.$noOfChannels.' and minchannel<='.$noOfChannels)->one();
    $coloursettings = models\Coloursetting::find()->one();
    $RowsColumn = $this->getRowandColumns($noOfChannels);
    return $this->render('boxedmainscreen', ['width'=>Yii::$app->session->get('width'), 'height'=>Yii::$app->session->get('height'), 'rows'=>$RowsColumn['rows'], 'columns'=>$RowsColumn['columns'],'noOfChannels'=>$noOfChannels, 'screensettings'=>$screenadjust, 'channels'=>$channels,'coloursettings'=>$coloursettings]);
}
```

I expect the page to be displayed but it says

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE
>   datalogger.GetWebChannels does not exist

The SQL being executed was: Call GetWebChannels()

Comment: Your procedure `GetWebChannels`  is not exist in mysql.

Comment: @InsaneSkull That is what i cant understand what is the apt meaning for that

Comment: You have stored procedure in your mysql which is not currently exist . Find this procedure in backup database first. [Mysql Stored Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

Comment: i imported my old database which works fine before also not working now, how to find that missing procedure

Comment: @RiggsFolly ...?